# Executing a python script via PHP on a remote server and display it's output

Tags: php, python

I'm trying to execute a python script via a PHP page and display the script output on the same PHP web page. Python script will access a remote server and read a file in it and pass the output to PHP web page.

Question I'm facing is, PHP page is displaying only the output which is given by the script's during it's local execution nothing from the remote file read.

What can be the issue here,  is it getting timeout? PHP code is;

```
cron job: <input type="text" name="cron_job"><input type="submit" value="Submit">
<?php
    if (isset ($_GET['cron_job']))
    {
            $cron_job = $_GET['cron_job'];
        $cron_job = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $cron_job);
            echo ($cron_job);

        $command = escapeshellcmd('/opt/lampp/htdocs/remote_file_read/remote_file_read.py tpfwdshw@ldngfwdapp01' .$cron_job);
        $file = $cron_job.".txt";
        $read_file_line = file('/opt/lampp/htdocs/remote_file_read/tmp_output_files/'.$file);
        foreach ($read_file_line as $line)
                {
                     echo htmlspecialchars($line) . '<br>';
                }
    }
```

Comment: you have a syntax error. `...wdapp01' $cron_job);` is not valid. forgot a `.`, maybe?

Comment: Thanks Marc. I tried it too, but no luck...

Comment: are you SURE that the python script is actually executing? php may be working perfectly and displaying what it finds: nothing, because python screwed up

Comment: Yes. python script is executing correctly...